Multinomial-Like Regression Model with indiscernible Outcomes
I've looked around a bit for the answer to this, and haven't found anything. I'm hoping that someone has already considered this particular system and that there is an existing model. I have a particular underlying behavior in mind, but I'll try to describe the general problem and then move on to the specific idea I have in mind. I guess this is technically two questions, so I'll try to delineate the different sections.
(I) A Multinomial Regression Model with Indiscernible Outcomes
I'm looking for a regression model that can fit a multinomial system in which one or more of the outcomes are indiscernible. The typical multinomial models I've found assume that outcomes can be differentiated.
Take, for example, and ordeal system in which you have four states: A < B < C < D. The probability of being in one of those states depends on some independent test variable over which you have control. In the mutlinomial model systems I've found, all of these states can be discerned, so you can clearly determine the outcome of (for example) a test.
But now say that you have a slightly different system in which A < B < A' < C, and in which A and A' appear to be identical states. In this situation, it will seem like state A repeats itself of some larger value of the test independent variable condition. But in the actual context of the test, we only know that we applied the independent test variable condition at some (continuous) value and observed state A, and have no independent way to know if we are in state A or A'.
For the purposes of this, let's suppose that applying the independent test variable to the sample is a destructive process, so you cannot simply ramp the independent test variable over a single sample in order to see changes from A to B to A' to C. Rather, you instantaneously apply the condition described by the independent variable, which makes further testing on that particular sample impossible. The data you get from this are pairs that link a particular independent variable condition to a state for a series of trials across the samples. E.g.
[0.2, A]; [0.2, B]; [0.2, A]; [0.3, B]; [0.3, B]; [0.3, A]; ...
where each bracket pair represents a single trial on a sample.
The only way I've found to do something like this is a high-order multinomial regression model (e.g. a multinomial regression model with 3rd or 4th order terms). While this works, it doesn't seem to respect the underlying structure of the problem in a particularly satisfying way.
The question is if there is an established way to analyze data from this system.
(II) Windowed-States
I have a particular idea on how to inefficiently model this behavior. I'm hoping there is something more efficient than brute-forcing it.
Suppose you have a population described by three parameters, and each parameter is given by a random variable: X, Y, and Z. These parameters are drawn from three separate continuous distributions, $\mathcal P_X$, $\mathcal P_Y$, and $\mathcal P_Z$, all of which have the property that they have support on (0,$\infty$); for example, a log-normal distribution. You cannot directly observe the values of X, Y, and Z. Rather, you observe according the following rules:
(1) If the test condition is less than X and Z for a particular sample, you observe state A;
(2) if the test condition is between X and X+Y but less than Z, you observe state B;
(3) if the test condition is greater than X+Y but less than Z, you observe state A;
(4) if the test condition is greater than Z, you observe state C.
As above, the test is destructive, so you only get one chance to observe a single paired state for any given sample.
Now obviously, you can choose your distributions such that you would always ever only see something like state C (e.g. choose the median of distribution $\mathcal P_Z$ to be much smaller than $\mathcal P_X$ or something like that), but lets actually arrange these distributions such that we get something interesting, namely an arrangement in which all 4 conditions are likely to occur for some of the samples.
In this system, the default state is A, and we have something like a "window of efficacy" for state B. Beyond a certain condition though, we will always be in state C.
The window for which we could see state B is dependent on the random properties X and Y (so long as Z is sufficiently greater than X).
This is similar to what I described in (I), and for particular distributions I would see something similar to what I saw in (I). But here I've attached some underlying threshold model to the behavior.
The only way I have figured to try to fit data to a model like this is by brute-force, that is use a computer to simulate outcomes of millions of trials, compare the simulation to the actual results via some cost function, and then try to minimize the cost-function. This is not a particularly fast process, and I've found that it is not particularly stable either (although that might be because of my choice of cost function).
Again, the question is whether or not there is an efficient way to analyze data from this system, hopefully one that would provide the parameters for the underlying distributions (so long as I had a guess as the character of the distributions)?

Hi @Doctor, welcome to CV. This is not close to my area of specialty at all, so hopefully others can jump in with useful responses. And I don't fully understand the question either. However, this sounds similar to a latent variable system or Hidden Markov Model. Might be a useful way to think about your problem. All the best :)

It feels like both examples relate to ill-posed inverse problems, in which there is first a data generating mechanism and then a censoring mechanism. This is a very general class of problems, and so the solutions in the literature are very open-ended and will depend on your specific constraints – I can try to point to some keywords to help you. An important question should be whether you wish to infer parameters based on a likelihood (and perform exact inference), or if you are okay with approximate solutions (but e.g. care more about computational efficiency).
As mentioned, this problem can be treated in a latent variable approach, so that you will explicitly introduce the values of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ as hidden variables. The EM Algorithm, Gibbs sampling and Metropolis-Hastings are then algorithms used to train latent variable models and which will give you exact inference answers.
There has also been recent progress in ML/comp stats to infer such models while not running data augmentation. Your idea of sampling cases, censoring them and comparing them with a cost function is very close to methods of "sampling-based loss functions" and "approximate Bayesian computation". People have tried to find tricks to reduce the computational cost of these techniques, but they rely on problem-specific aspects.
The specific example of multinomial data with merged categories feels very similar to "ecological inference", which has been traditionally solved with data augmentation (notably Gibbs). It depends, however, on being able to express the censoring as a linear filter: with data $W$ following a multinomial and $A$ a fixed matrix, and only observing $AW$.
